# How to configure /etc/pam.d/sshd and nsswitch.conf in order to avoid all remote calls for ssh with local user?

Tags: ssh, pam, nsswitch, nss

I have created an NSS and a PAM module in order to authenticate and get users and groups from a custom remote server.

In order to get them used by the system I am adding a line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth       sufficient   myPAMmodule.so
```

and in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:     files sss myNSSmodule
shadow:     files sss myNSSmodule
group:      files sss myNSSmodule
```

The question is how to configure these (or anything else) in order to avoid calling my modules in case an ssh is made with a local user.

Adding a linux module with sufficient before my module

```
auth       sufficient  pam_env.so
```

seems necessary. By adding an initgroups line without my module

```
initgroups: files sss
```

makes id command to work only locally for local user ( but gets only primary group for user).

But still whenever I perform `ssh user@localhost` I still see remote calls for local users.